# Unable to see Install button on PWA developed on Angular using service workers after publish

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I have angular version 12.2. I am using Service Worker. When I run on localhost it works fine and displays install button on browser. But when I deploy it to my server or IIS server, install button doesn't show.
Here is the picture of localhost
[image]

I have followed all the steps mentioned on Angular website
[Getting started with service workers](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started)

Comment: Are you sure that all service worker files are uploaded on your server ?
And have you check in your app.module.ts file that the ServiceWorkerModule is enable in prod ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by applying the following steps

1. Create Web.Config file in dist folder (created after build)
2. Add configuration in web.config file

   ```
   <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <staticContent>
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".webmanifest" mimeType="application/json" />
       </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
   ```